# How To Manage Tablespace in DB2

Tags: db2

my table space keeps getting full. I want to know which tables i can truncate for freeing the space. How i can  identify the culprit tables?
I found out which tables are using most no of partitions but is that the only way I can get to know that this table is the culprit.
What should I do to manage the table space and send an alert message when the utilization is over 70%?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the amount of space used for each table using this query.

```
 select name, npages from sysibm.systables order by npages desc fetch first 20 rows only
```

To manage your tablespace, you can set up a cronjob and look for (Used pages/Useable pages) and send an alert if it's over 70% used.

```
db2 list tablespaces show detail
```